# inner class vs clase anonima

Tags: java

Supuestamente ambos bloques de codigo son equivalentes, sin embargo no me queda claro como el segundo bloque consigue hacer lo mismo, podrian explicarlo por favor.

```
    class ClickListener implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public ClickListener() {
            System.out.println("I've been attached");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(String title) {
            System.out.println(title + " was clicked");
        }
    }

    btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String title) {
            System.out.println(title + " was clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer bloque (Inner class) define una clase con nombre, que puede ser referenciada varias veces con el operador new.

El segundo bloque (Anonymous class), esta definiendo una clase e instanciandola en el mismo momento sin asignarle ningun nombre. Al no existir referencia de la clase del segundo bloque, esta no puede ser instanciada mas de una vez.